# Invalid Cast Exception: Unable to cast object of type '__DynamicallyInvokableAttribute' to type 'BugFixApplication.DeBugInfo'

Tags: c#, exception, casting, runtime-error

I tried to type cast Attribute variable to DeBugInfo type.

Here's the code in Main function in class ExecuteRectangle:

```
class ExecuteRectangle
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(4.5, 7.5);
        r.Display();
        Type type = typeof(Rectangle);
        //iterating through the attribtues of the Rectangle class
        foreach (Object attributes in type.GetCustomAttributes(false))
        {
            DeBugInfo dbi = (DeBugInfo)attributes;
            if (null != dbi)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bug no: {0}", dbi.BugNo);
                Console.WriteLine("Developer: {0}", dbi.Developer);
                Console.WriteLine("Last Reviewed: {0}",
                     dbi.LastReview);
                Console.WriteLine("Remarks: {0}", dbi.Message);
            }
        }

        //iterating through the method attribtues
        foreach (MethodInfo m in type.GetMethods())
        {
            foreach (Attribute a in m.GetCustomAttributes(true))
            {
                DeBugInfo dbi = (DeBugInfo)a;
                if (null != dbi)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bug no: {0}, for Method: {1}",
                          dbi.BugNo, m.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("Developer: {0}", dbi.Developer);
                    Console.WriteLine("Last Reviewed: {0}",
                          dbi.LastReview);
                    Console.WriteLine("Remarks: {0}", dbi.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here's the DeBugInfo class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class |
AttributeTargets.Constructor |
AttributeTargets.Field |
AttributeTargets.Method |
AttributeTargets.Property,
AllowMultiple = true)]

public class DeBugInfo : Attribute
{
    private int bugNo;
    private string developer;
    private string lastReview;
    public string message;

    public DeBugInfo(int bg, string dev, string d)
    {
        this.bugNo = bg;
        this.developer = dev;
        this.lastReview = d;
    }

    public int BugNo
    {
        get
        {
            return bugNo;
        }
    }
    public string Developer
    {
        get
        {
            return developer;
        }
    }
    public string LastReview
    {
        get
        {
            return lastReview;
        }
    }
    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return message;
        }
        set
        {
            message = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And the class Rectangle:

```
  [DeBugInfo(45, "Zara Ali", "12/8/2012",
 Message = "Return type mismatch")]
[DeBugInfo(49, "Nuha Ali", "10/10/2012",
 Message = "Unused variable")]
class Rectangle
{
    //member variables
    protected double length;
    protected double width;
    public Rectangle(double l, double w)
    {
        length = l;
        width = w;
    }
    [DeBugInfo(55, "Zara Ali", "19/10/2012",
     Message = "Return type mismatch")]
    public double GetArea()
    {
        return length * width;
    }
    [DeBugInfo(56, "Zara Ali", "19/10/2012")]
    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", length);
        Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
        Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", GetArea());
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get the desired output which is this:

```
Length: 4.5
Width: 7.5
Area: 33.75
Bug No: 49
Developer: Nuha Ali
Last Reviewed: 10/10/2012
Remarks: Unused variable
Bug No: 45
Developer: Zara Ali
Last Reviewed: 12/8/2012
Remarks: Return type mismatch
Bug No: 55, for Method: GetArea
Developer: Zara Ali
Last Reviewed: 19/10/2012
Remarks: Return type mismatch
Bug No: 56, for Method: Display
Developer: Zara Ali
Last Reviewed: 19/10/2012
Remarks:
```

But I also get this unhandled exception error and program crashes:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type       
'__DynamicallyInvokableAttribute' to type 'BugFixApplication.DeBugInfo' at 
BugFixApplication.ExecuteRectangle.Main(string[] args)
```

I don't know why I get this exception nor how I can fix this.

Comment: I don't get the question. Clearly one of the attributes you get is not `DeBugInfo`. Have you looked at the attributes returned from `type.GetCustomAttributes(false)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach (Object attributes in type.GetCustomAttributes(false))
{
    DeBugInfo dbi = attributes as DeBugInfo;
    if (null != dbi)
    {
        .....
```

Use same for method attributes.

Comment: wow +2 without any explanation and doing a shot in the dark congrats!

Comment: @Mark could you please explain why the behavior is like that?

Comment: @AsisDatta because the `type.GetCustomAttributes()` method returns attributes with different types. Using this cast syntax `(DeBugInfo)attributes` implies that the `attributes` variable can always and definitely be casted to `DeBugInfo`. The error means that this is not the case. There are `attributes` that can not be casted to `DeBugInfo`. So, using `attributes as DeBugInfo` causes it to try to cast, but returns null if it can't. Which is why the next line of the answer checks for null. The `if` block will only handle attributes that can be casted to `DeBugInfo`.